# Color-thief.js Cannot read property 'width' of undefined

Tags: javascript, html, color-thief

I'm struggling to make color-thief works, I think that my code is right so, I don't understand if it comes from the color-thief script or mine.

Here's my code so far :

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="fr">
<head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">


    src=" <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>"></script>
    <script src="color-thief.js"></script>

    <style type="text/css">
        #mydiv {
            width: 100px;
            height: 100px;
            border: 1px solid #000;
        }
    </style>

</head>


<body>

    <div id="mydiv"></div>
    <img src="image/image_test.png" id="myImg" />


<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var sourceImage = document.getElementById("myImg");
        var colorThief = new ColorThief();
        color = colorThief.getColor(sourceImage[0]);
        alert(color);
    // document.getElementById("mydiv").style.backgroundColor = "rgb(" + color + ")"; 
    });
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

I would like to alert the RGB of the color, and in my console, I have this error :

```
> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'width' of undefined
>     at new CanvasImage (color-thief.js:33)
>     at ColorThief.getPalette (color-thief.js:109)
>     at ColorThief.getColor (color-thief.js:76)
>     at index.html:32
```

Thanks

Comment: You probably need to move your code into an `onload` event handler so it runs after the DOM has finished loading.  Using jQuery this would be `$(document).ready(function() { /* your code here */ })`.

Comment: Still doesn't work...

Comment: That doesn't tell me much.  Is it the same error?  Is `sourceImage` an element or is it undefined?

Comment: still "Cannot read property 'width' of undefined" but on more objects now

Comment: It works on Safari but not on Google Chrome... It's weird.

Answer (score 0):

This error has happen to me when calling getColor or GetPallete with wrong arguments.

I think the error you have is caused by 
`color = colorThief.getColor(sourceImage[0]);`
try with
`color = colorThief.getColor(sourceImage);`

But i would suggest you to try to invoke colorThief on the Load event of your img.